# Sorting a two-dimensional array of doubles in C

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, quicksort

I'm trying to sort with qsort a two-dimensional array in C.

I have this array:

```
{ {1.0, 0.0}, {123.0, 1.0}, {2.0, 2.0} }
```

and I want it to be sorted by the second value like that:

```
{ {1.0, 0.0}, {2.0, 2.0}, {123.0, 1.0} }
```

I've tried to write an array comparator for qsort but I always get the wrong order of elements.

This is the comparator I wrote:

```
int CompareArrays(const void* arr1, const void* arr2) {

 const double* one = (const double*) arr1;
 const double* two = (const double*) arr2;
 printf ("one[0] = %lf , one[1] = %lf \n", one[0], one[1]);
 printf ("two[0] = %lf , two[1] = %lf \n", two[0], two[1]);
 if (one[0] < two[0]) return -1;
 if (one[0] > two[0]) return 1;

 return 0;
}
```

I also tried to print the values in order to understand what items are being compared each time, but it keeps printing 0.0000... every time.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using [`qsort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort)? *How* do you call `qsort`? With what arguments? Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: Are you aware that sorting a 2d array is not trivial? I mean, you need to be very clear about what you mean by **sort** the array.

Comment: You need to show more of the code. The call to qsort should be qsort(pointer_to_first_row, num_of_rows, size_of_row, compare_function); . Note that qsort will be passing pointer to pointer to row to the compare function.

Comment: You are comparing the first value.  If you want to sort by the second value:  `return two[1] - one[1];`

Comment: On the face of it, you are either wanting to sort on the first (zeroth) element of each sub-array, or you have your input and output back to front.  The call to `qsort()` will be important, but I suspect that you are (or should be) being given `double (*)[2]` values, but that's not what you've written in your comparator, so you're not sorting correctly.  Make sure you can print the data in each of the two arrays you're passed.  If you only get 'zeros' (was that printed using `%f` or `%e` or `%g` format?), then you're probably accessing garbage — and you're unlucky it isn't crashing.

Comment: How is your result sorted by the second value?

Comment: @stark, won't your suggestion of `return two[1] - one[1];` cause 1.0 to compare equal to 1.1 since the result of the comparison function is int?

Answer (score 1):

The problem folks are having trying to help you is that your text says one thing (sort by second element) but your example shows another (sort by first element).  Let's first assume "sort by first element" and solve the problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int compareArrays(const void *array1, const void *array2) {
    const double *one = (const double *) array1;
    const double *two = (const double *) array2;

    return (one[0] > two[0]) - (one[0] < two[0]); // compare idiom
}

#define SUBELEMENTS (2)

void printArray(double array[][SUBELEMENTS], size_t rows) {
    printf("{");

    for (size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        printf("{");

        for (size_t j = 0; j < SUBELEMENTS; j++) {
            printf("%.1f", array[i][j]);

            if (SUBELEMENTS > 1 && j < SUBELEMENTS - 1) {
                printf(", ");
            }
        }

        printf("}");

        if (rows > 1 && i < rows - 1) {
            printf(", ");
        }
    }

    printf("}\n");
}

int main() {
    double array[][SUBELEMENTS] = {{1.0, 0.0}, {123.0, 1.0}, {2.0, 2.0}};

    size_t elements = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);

    printf("Unsorted: ");
    printArray(array, elements);

    qsort(array, elements, sizeof array[0], &compareArrays);

    printf("Sorted:   ");
    printArray(array, elements);

    return 0;
}
```

If you really wanted "sort by second element", then change the last line of `compareArrays()` to:

```
return (one[1] > two[1]) - (one[1] < two[1]);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> ./a.out
Unsorted: {{1.0, 0.0}, {123.0, 1.0}, {2.0, 2.0}}
Sorted:   {{1.0, 0.0}, {2.0, 2.0}, {123.0, 1.0}}
>
```